# Are there any non-cloud web analytics platforms for IIS/.Net?

Tags: asp.net, iis, google-analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I am wondering if there exists a web analytics product that meets these criteria:

- Can be installed on private server, not using anything cloud-based
- Can be installed on IIS/.Net and does not require PHP, or any server side language beyond ASP.NET
- Can use a local SQL Server as its datastore (not MySQL or any kind of cloud storage)
- Can work with an internal intranet web application without a fully qualified domain name
- Can track page views and button clicks using simple JavaScript and/or C# APIs
- Is free or at least cheap

I am trying to avoid installing PHP on IIS to run Piwik or something similar, and this is a last ditch effort.  My searches are turning up nothing.

Comment: better try your luck on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Piwik (php) is the only reasonable alternative to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is no.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Until a few years ago Webtrends (www.webtrends.com) was providing exactly what you are looking for (even if it is not for free).
I am not sure, though, if the On Premise version of their software is still available.

Hope this helps!